# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-23: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, ascii, encode

I tried to fit the model but got one weird error
So, I have Win10(64), Python 3.7
This is my code:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(solver='saga')
param_grid = {
    'C': np.arange(1, 5),
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
}
search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5, refit=True, scoring='accuracy')
search.fit(feature_matrix, labels)
```

And this is traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-93a1aa3c1ec2> in <module>
     12 
     13 
---> 14 search.fit(feature_matrix, labels)
     15 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    693                                     verbose=self.verbose)
    694         results = {}
--> 695         with parallel:
    696             all_candidate_params = []
    697             all_out = []

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __enter__(self)
    709     def __enter__(self):
    710         self._managed_backend = True
--> 711         self._initialize_backend()
    712         return self
    713 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _initialize_backend(self)
    720         try:
    721             n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
--> 722                                              **self._backend_args)
    723             if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:
    724                 warnings.warn(

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, prefer, require, idle_worker_timeout, **memmappingexecutor_args)
    495             n_jobs, timeout=idle_worker_timeout,
    496             env=self._prepare_worker_env(n_jobs=n_jobs),
--> 497             context_id=parallel._id, **memmappingexecutor_args)
    498         self.parallel = parallel
    499         return n_jobs

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     18 
     19 def get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs):
---> 20     return MemmappingExecutor.get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     21 
     22 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(cls, n_jobs, timeout, initializer, initargs, env, temp_folder, context_id, **backend_args)
     40         _executor_args = executor_args
     41 
---> 42         manager = TemporaryResourcesManager(temp_folder)
     43 
     44         # reducers access the temporary folder in which to store temporary

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in __init__(self, temp_folder_root, context_id)
    529             # exposes exposes too many low-level details.
    530         context_id = uuid4().hex
--> 531         self.set_current_context(context_id)
    532 
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in set_current_context(self, context_id)
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):
    534         self._current_context_id = context_id
--> 535         self.register_new_context(context_id)
    536 
    537     def register_new_context(self, context_id):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_new_context(self, context_id)
    558                 new_folder_name, self._temp_folder_root
    559             )
--> 560             self.register_folder_finalizer(new_folder_path, context_id)
    561             self._cached_temp_folders[context_id] = new_folder_path
    562 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_folder_finalizer(self, pool_subfolder, context_id)
    588         # semaphores and pipes
    589         pool_module_name = whichmodule(delete_folder, 'delete_folder')
--> 590         resource_tracker.register(pool_subfolder, "folder")
    591 
    592         def _cleanup():

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in register(self, name, rtype)
    189         '''Register a named resource, and increment its refcount.'''
    190         self.ensure_running()
--> 191         self._send('REGISTER', name, rtype)
    192 
    193     def unregister(self, name, rtype):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in _send(self, cmd, name, rtype)
    202 
    203     def _send(self, cmd, name, rtype):
--> 204         msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('ascii')
    205         if len(name) > 512:
    206             # posix guarantees that writes to a pipe of less than PIPE_BUF

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to fix the _send by cutting .encode('ascii'), but it didn't help me. It generates another error (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str') with variable msg from the traceback above
I'm looking for advice about this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: try encoding it to 'utf-8' instead of ascii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding using `utf-8`.

```
msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('utf-8')
```

These messages usually means that you’re trying to either mix `Unicode strings` with `8-bit strings`, or is trying to write Unicode strings to an output file or device that only handles `ASCII`.

When you do this, Python will usually assume that the 8-bit string contains ASCII data only, and will raise an error if this is not the case.

The best way to avoid this on input is to `convert all incoming strings to Unicode`, do the processing in Unicode, and then convert back to encoded byte strings on the way out.

Comment: It's great!!!! Thank you.
As I thought the solution is very easy. I met this problem several times and now all work correctly and I'm happy))))

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem, can you accept it as the answer? :)